# How to get pyside-uic to generate "./" for resources instead of ":/"

Tags: pyside, qt-designer

I have a GUI I created with QtDesigner that includes some images for buttons. Within QtDesigner they are stored together in a resource file. When I run `pyside-uic -x ui_mainWindow.ui -o ui_mainWindow.py` or `pyside-uic -o ui_mainWindow.py ui_mainWindow.ui`, the resulting python code includes lines like:

```
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/assets/CU LASP.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
```

but I want it to say

```
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("./assets/CU LASP.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
```

(just use a ./ instead of a :/). When I run the python code with the :/, the images don't show up. When I do a hard code change to ./, the images do show up.

Comment: The default search path is to search only in the root. Maybe try https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QDir.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QDir.addSearchPath

Comment: I'd like not to have to do any manual editing to the .py file since it gets replaced every time I do an update in QtDesigner and then run pyside-uic.

Comment: You also need to compile a resource module with `pyside-rcc`.

Comment: That's true, and I've tried. That too results in an error saying it can't find the image(s). But I thought that was a separate issue from this.